# Symfony2: Login form work true, but I have no access to Login Information {{ app.user }}

Tags: security, symfony, twig

In base template **base.html.twig** i write this code

```
  {% if app.user %}
    <a href="{{ path('logout') }}">Logout</a>
  {% else %}
    <a href="{{ path('register') }}">register</a> |
    <a href="{{ path('login') }}">Login</a>
  {% endif %}
```

after *LOGIN* 
  in /profile i see Logout link in menu
  but
  in / (and other page) i see register and login link in menu

```
security:
    ...
    providers:
        administartors:
            entity: { class: DotArtBundle:User, property: username }

    firewalls:
        profile:
            pattern:    ^/profile
            http_basic: ~
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                check_path:  /profile/login_action
                login_path:  /login
                use_forward: false
                username_parameter: _username
                password_parameter: _password
            logout:
                path:   /profile/logout
                target: /
                invalidate_session: false
        login:
            pattern:  ^/login
            security: false

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login,         roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/profile,       roles: ROLE_USER  }
        - { path: ^/profile/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

How i could solve this problem?

**Solution:**

I change `pattern:    ^/profile` to `pattern:    ^/`

Answer (score 2):

On side tip, according to the logged in/out check. Using is_granted should be more reliable for future updates.

```
{% if is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED') %}
  <a href="{{ path('logout') }}">Logout</a>
{% else %}
  <a href="{{ path('register') }}">register</a> |
  <a href="{{ path('login') }}">Login</a>
{% endif %}
```